# Generar tabla agrupada SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Espero me de a entender con el titulo pero no encuentro otra manera de decirlo, veran necesito obtener el estado de animo por area tengo una tabla con los siguientes campos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos de obtienen mediante una encuesta en una pagina web, en ella solicita el numero de usuario, el area al que pertenecem y mediante indicadores (Checkbox) el usuario selecciona su estado de animo, en base a esta informacion 
necesito generar un tabla como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta el momento he logrado agrupar y contar los status con:

```
select 
count(*) as total, area, Status 
from [EstadosDeAnimo] 
inner join Areas on EstadosDeAnimo.AreaId = Area.areaId 
group by area,Status order by area
```

obteniendo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y como se llega a la clasificación de Feliz, Triste y Regular?

Comment: qué has intentado hasta ahora y no te ha valido y por qué

Comment: La clasificacion se obtiene mediante un indicador de checkbox en mi pagina web, no es muy compleja dependiendo del checkbox es el valor (Feliz,triste y regular). hasta ahora he intentado un simple group by y quizas si funciona pero me gustaria tener doble alternativa ya sea mostrar literalmente esa tabla o con esa consulta generar una grafica.

Comment: Porque queres resolver esto en un query (nesecitas una tabla pivotante, o hacer un case con multiples opciones) cuando claramente parece que tu problema se resuelve solo en el programa que muestra esos datos? solo ordenas y mandas a la columna que corresponda la cuenta...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.Area,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EA.Status = 'Happy' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)   AS Feliz,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EA.Status = 'Sad' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)     AS Triste,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EA.Status = 'Regular' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Regular
       FROM Areas A 
       LEFT JOIN EstadosDeAnimo EA
           ON EA.areaId= A.areaId
      GROUP BY A.area
      ORDER BY A.area
```

Puedes hacer un suma condicional según el estado. Te sugiero además que partas de `Areas` como base de tu consulta y usar un `left join` con `EstadosDeAnimo`, para asegurarte que se muestren todas las áreas independientemente que tengan `EstadosDeAnimo`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un count por estado y agruparlos por area de la siguiente forma.

```
SELECT A.Area,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM EstadosDeAnimo WHERE Status = 'Happy' AND areaId =A.areaId) AS Feliz,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM EstadosDeAnimo WHERE Status = 'Sad' AND areaId =A.areaId) AS Triste ,
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM EstadosDeAnimo WHERE Status = 'Regular' AND areaId =A.areaId) AS Regular
FROM [EstadosDeAnimo] AS EA
INNER JOIN Areas AS A ON EA.areaId= A.areaId
GROUP BY A.area,A.areaId
ORDER BY A.area
```